How to design a Dataflow pipeline requiring several external api calls and database operations per flow?
The pipeline I am building is specifically using Dataflow with Apache Beam Python's sdk, however, I just need opinions on Beam's concepts, so examples in Java for instance I am very fine with.
In essence, the messages coming into the pipeline are very incomplete, so I will have to be constantly making calls to an external api to expand on this data to be able to process it. Moreover, some cases will also require to read from a SQL database to further enrich this data. Most of the time the last step of the flow will be a database write or an output to a PubSub topic, however, in some cases I will also need to make calls to the same external api to update data there as a side effect. These operations sometimes can happen over 10 times per single message pulled.
So with that in mind, what is the best overall architecture to use here?
The very first solution I went with basically relied on doing all those calls and database queries inside the same DoFn, but I am not sure that is even close to optimal. I have considered using side inputs to maintain a short-lived cache of the api data, and basically refresh it before processing data on each message pulled. I have also considered using side outputs to be able to do the multiple writes (to external api and to database). I have read in the docs that it could be useful to use the enrichment submodule to be able to create ParDos for the api and database calls that can essentially be used by Dataflow to batch these operations. However, this submodule seems to assume that the calls are done to a lookup table, and not a more classical POST request.
I just need some opinions from people who have faced similar cases to give me an idea of what I should be aiming for, and potentially what I should be avoiding.

I think https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/enrichment/ should be a good fit here. You can define your own handler if needed: https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.enrichment.html#apache_beam.transforms.enrichment.EnrichmentSourceHandler
